# When to play Amen

Tags: church-music

When playing Christmas songs during a Church Service, if the song's music has an Amen at the end, you play it. If the same song, being played as a Christmas Carol that a choir is singing, then you don't play the Amen. Is this correct?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Whether 'Amen' is appended to every hymn during a service is completely down to the traditions of the individual church.  I don't hear it much.  Maybe your church likes it. Fine.   During a Carol Service or concert I'd say no.   But, if a clergyman is involved, ask him.

Comment: I think he's asking about outside of church.